# Maintain dual login strategy in web browser?

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-session

I'm creating a web app with a node (server) + graphql + react (client). For authentication purpose simply using express-session and cookie parser. But here I want to maintain separate login Panels for admin and normal users. So I want to create a dual login session in chrome (both admin user and a normal user can log in with chrome browser simultaneously).

While trying to create a session after the other then the previous session not exists. So I'm not able to maintain 2 sessions for admin and normal users respectively.

Surfing internet giving solutions like using passport.js, But I want to do this process using express session.

Anyone please redirect me through the right path.

Comment: How are you storing session IDs on the client?  You could use a particular cookie path, or just use LocalStorage in a custom way.

Comment: Hi Brad, Just using LocalStorage   cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 1800000,
      secure: false
    }